# Improve this AngularJS factory to use with socket.io

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I want to use socket.io in AngularJS.
I found the following factory:

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    };
```

and it is used in the controller like:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, socket) {
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        ...
    });
};
```

the problem is that each time the controller is visited another listener is added, so when a message is received it is handled multiple times.

what can be a better strategy to integrate socket.io with AngularJS ?

EDIT: I know that I can return nothing in the factory and do the listening there, then use $rootScope.$broadcast and $scope.$on in the controllers, but it doesn't look like a good solution.

EDIT2: added to the factory

```
init: function() {
            socket.removeAllListeners();
}
```

and call it at the beginning of each controller that use socket.io.

still doesn't feel like the best solution.

Comment: Source of the socketio factory: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/

Comment: this is also my problem

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Remove the socket listeners whenever the controller is destroyed. 
You will need to bind the `$destroy` event like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, socket) {
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        ...
    });

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
        socket.removeAllListeners();
        // or something like
        // socket.removeListener(this);
    });
};
```

For more information check the [angularjs documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24destroy).

Comment: Error: socket.removeListeners is not a function

Comment: @waqas You have to encapsulate socket into a service.

Comment: I just figured out a good solution to this issue. Check out my answer below.

Comment: @bmleite: What about if i've one controller like `footerCtrl` that include in every route using `ng-include`

Answer (score 8):

You might be able to handle this with a minimal amount of work by wrapping up a Scope and watching for `$destroy` to be broadcast, and when it is, only removing from the socket the listeners that were added in the context of that Scope. Be warned: what follows hasn't been tested--I'd treat it more like pseudocode than actual code. :)

```javascript
// A ScopedSocket is an object that provides `on` and `emit` methods,
// but keeps track of all listeners it registers on the socket.
// A call to `removeAllListeners` will remove all listeners on the
// socket that were created via this particular instance of ScopedSocket.

var ScopedSocket = function(socket, $rootScope) {
  this.socket = socket;
  this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
  this.listeners = [];
};

ScopedSocket.prototype.removeAllListeners = function() {
  // Remove each of the stored listeners
  for(var i = 0; i < this.listeners.length; i++) {
    var details = this.listeners[i];
    this.socket.removeListener(details.event, details.fn);
  };
};

ScopedSocket.prototype.on = function(event, callback) {
  var socket = this.socket;
  var $rootScope = this.$rootScope;

  var wrappedCallback = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      callback.apply(socket, args);
    });
  };

  // Store the event name and callback so we can remove it later
  this.listeners.push({event: event, fn: wrappedCallback});

  socket.on(event, wrappedCallback);
};

ScopedSocket.prototype.emit = function(event, data, callback) {
  var socket = this.socket;
  var $rootScope = this.$rootScope;

  socket.emit(event, data, function() {
    var args = arguments;
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      if (callback) {
        callback.apply(socket, args);
      }
    });
  });
};

app.factory('Socket', function($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();

  // When injected into controllers, etc., Socket is a function
  // that takes a Scope and returns a ScopedSocket wrapping the
  // global Socket.IO `socket` object. When the scope is destroyed,
  // it will call `removeAllListeners` on that ScopedSocket.
  return function(scope) {
    var scopedSocket = new ScopedSocket(socket, $rootScope);
    scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      scopedSocket.removeAllListeners();
    });
    return scopedSocket;
  };
});

function MyController($scope, Socket) {
  var socket = Socket($scope);

  socket.on('message', function(data) {
     ...
  });
};
```

Comment: do you use this object directly in a controller ?

Comment: At the bottom of the example, you can see the `Socket` service being injected into a controller, and an example of how you would go about using it. Does that answer your question, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I've been grappling with the same problem and I wonder if the simpler approach is to hoist all the socket.on calls to be on $rootScope. In my case, incoming socket.io events affect the ng-view, so moving them to be on $rootScope prevents (I think) the problem @GalBen-Haim faced. One problem with this approach is that those pieces of your model that are modified by incoming socket.io messages need to also be in the $rootScope. For now, I prefer doing this and keeping the solution simple. Injecting $rootScope into the other controllers allows them to directly access the necessary model parts.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution! I'll try it out, hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution! I'll try it out, hope it works. Nope, it didn't. You need to save the warpped callback for it to be removed properly. Like this: 
    var wrapped_callback = function() {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      };
      socket.on(event, wrapped_callback);
    
   this.listeners.push({
     event: event,
     fn: wrapped_callback
   });

Comment: @ManuelAráoz I'm sure there are issues with the code listed--that's why it says: "Be warned: what follows hasn't been tested--I'd treat it more like pseudocode than actual code." :) Please feel free to edit with updates. (Edit) I've updated the code.

Answer (score 5):

I would add a comment to the accepted answer, but i can't. So, i'll write a reply.
I had the same problem and the easiest and simplest answer i found is the one that you can find [here, on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22424757/1094045), provided by [michaeljoser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422332/michaeljoser).

I'll copy it below for convenience:

You have to add removeAllListeners to your factory (see below) and have the following code in each of your controllers:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
socket.removeAllListeners();
});
```

Updated socket factory:

```
var socket = io.connect('url');
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        },
      removeAllListeners: function (eventName, callback) {
          socket.removeAllListeners(eventName, function() {
              var args = arguments;
              $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
              });
          }); 
      }
    };
});
```

It saved my day, i hope it will be useful to someone else!

Comment: I had applied same code stil it does not work. multiple emits issue occurs. Can you guide me?

Answer (score 2):

create function in your *service or factory* like below.

```
unSubscribe: function(listener) {
    socket.removeAllListeners(listener);
}
```

and then call in your controller under the "$destroy" event like below.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    yourServiceName.unSubscribe('eventName');
});
```

that's solve

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a similar problem before I read this. I did it all in the Service.

```
.controller('AlertCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", "Socket", function($scope, $rootScope, Socket) {
    $scope.Socket = Socket;
}])

// this is where the alerts are received and passed to the controller then to the view
.factory('Socket', ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
    var Socket = {
        alerts: [],
        url: location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: ''),
        // io is coming from socket.io.js which is coming from Node.js
        socket: io.connect(this.url)
    };
    // set up the listener once
    // having this in the controller was creating a
    // new listener every time the contoller ran/view loaded
    // has to run after Socket is created since it refers to itself
    (function() {
        Socket.socket.on('get msg', function(data) {
            if (data.alert) {
                Socket.alerts.push(data.alert);
                $rootScope.$digest();
            }
        });
    }());
    return Socket;
}])
```

Comment: So how call it form controller?

Comment: Look at the first three lines of the code above. The service is injected into the controller and you would have access to it as `$scope.Socket.alerts`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. cleanest code, explains the most

Answer (score 1):

I tried different ways but nothing worked as expected.
In my app I'm using a `socket` factory in both the `MainController` and a `GameController`. When the user switches to a different view I only want to remove the duplicates events generated by the `GameController` and leave the `MainController` running so I cannot use a `removeAllListeners` function. Instead I discovered a better way to just avoid creating duplicates inside my `socket` factory:

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();

  function on(eventName, callback) {
    socket.on(eventName, function () {
      var args = arguments;

      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        callback.apply(socket, args);
      });
    });

    // Remove duplicate listeners
    socket.removeListener(eventName, callback);
  }

  function emit(eventName, data, callback) {
    socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
      var args = arguments;

      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        if (callback) {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        }
      });
    });

    // Remove duplicate listeners
    socket.removeListener(eventName, callback);
  }

  return {
    on: on,
    emit: emit
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing app.factory, create a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) (singleton) like so:

```
var service = angular.module('socketService', []);
service.factory('$socket', function() {
    // Your factory logic
});
```

You can then simply inject the service to your app and use it in controllers as you would $rootScope.

Here is a more complete example of how I have this set up:

```
// App module
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.services']);

// services
var services = angular.module('app.services', []);

// Socket service
services.factory('$socket', ['$rootScope', function(rootScope) {

    // Factory logic here

}]);

// Controller
app.controller('someController', ['$scope', '$socket', function(scope, socket) {

    // Controller logic here

}]);
```

Comment: what's the difference between this and my solution ?

Comment: Read the first line! A service is created only ones (singleton), so doing a io.connect in a service would create only one listener. I can confirm that this works.

Comment: This is not correct at all. ALL service in Angular are singletons. [Here is proof.](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/arPD9/) Calling `app.service` vs `app.factory`, etc. simply differs in the way the service is constructed (e.g. use `factory` if only `$get` is required in your service). The issue in this question is not creating multiple connections to Socket.IO, but the fact that listeners are not destroyed when a Controller (and its Scope) are destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Brandon's answer above, I've created a service that should additionally 1) strip angular tags like .$$hashKey that gets left on elements, and 2) allows for namespaced sockets like socketsof('..').on('..'

```
(function (window, app, undefined) {
    'use strict';


    var ScopedSocket = function (socket, $rootScope) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.listeners = [];
        this.childSockets = [];
    };

    ScopedSocket.prototype.removeAllListeners = function () {
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < this.listeners.length; i++) {
            var details = this.listeners[i];
            this.socket.removeListener(details.event, details.fn);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < this.childSockets.length; i++) {
            this.childSockets[i].removeAllListeners();
        }
    };

    ScopedSocket.prototype.on = function (event, callback) {
        var socket = this.socket;
        var $rootScope = this.$rootScope;

        this.listeners.push({event: event, fn: callback});

        socket.on(event, function () {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
        });
    };

    ScopedSocket.prototype.emit = function (event, data, callback) {
        var socket = this.socket;
        var $rootScope = this.$rootScope;

        socket.emit(event, angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(data)), function () {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                if (callback) {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    ScopedSocket.prototype.of = function (channel) {
        var childSocket = new ScopedSocket(this.socket.of(channel), this.$rootScope);

        this.childSockets.push(childSocket);

        return childSocket;
    };


    app.factory('Socket', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        var socket = $rootScope.socket;

        return function(scope) {
            var scopedSocket = new ScopedSocket(socket, $rootScope);
            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                scopedSocket.removeAllListeners();
            });
            return scopedSocket;
        };
    }]);
})(window, window.app);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like the code below.
socketsService is only instantiated once and I believe Angular takes care of GC the $on's

If you don't like $broadcast/$on, there are some slightly more solid Message Bus implementations for Angular available...

```
app.service('socketsService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var socket = window.io.connect();

    socket.on('info', function(data) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("info_received", data);
    });

    socket.emit('ready', "Hello");
}]);

app.controller("infoController",['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.$root.$on("info_received", function(e,data){
            console.log(data);
        });
        //...
    }]);

app.run(
    ['socketsService',
        function (socketsService) {
        //...
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by checking whether listener already exists. If you have multiple controllers that are all loaded at the same time (think of different page modules that all utilize socketIO), removing all registered listeners on `$destroy` would break the functionality of both the destroyed controller and all the controllers that are still loaded.

```
app.factory("SocketIoFactory", function ($rootScope) {
    var socket = null;
    var nodePath = "http://localhost:12345/";

    function listenerExists(eventName) {
        return socket.hasOwnProperty("$events") && socket.$events.hasOwnProperty(eventName);
    }

    return {
        connect: function () {
            socket = io.connect(nodePath);
        },
        connected: function () {
            return socket != null;
        },
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            if (!listenerExists(eventName)) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    };
});
```

This could be further improved by tracking which listeners were registered by which controller and removing only listeners that belong to destroyed controllers to clean up the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this to avoid duplicated listeners and works pretty well.

```
 on: function (eventName, callback) {
  //avoid duplicated listeners
  if (listeners[eventName] != undefined) return;

  socket.on(eventName, function () {
     var args = arguments;
     $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        callback.apply(socket, args);
     });
     listeners[eventName] = true;
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem of duplicate events after a browser refresh.  I was using a 'factory', but switched to use a 'service'. Here's my socket.io wrapper:

```
myApp.service('mysocketio',['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{
    var socket = io.connect();

    return {

        on: function(eventName, callback )
        {
            socket.on(eventName, function()
            {
                var args=arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function()
                {
                    callback.apply(socket,args);
                });
            });
        },

        emit: function(eventName,data,callback)
        {
            socket.emit(eventName,data,function()
            {
                var args=arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function()
                {
                    if(callback)
                    {
                        callback.apply(socket,args);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }

}]);
```

I use this service inside my controller and listen for events:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['mysocketio', function(mysocketio)
{
    mysocketio.on( 'myevent', function(msg)
    {
        console.log('received event: ' + msg );
    }
}]);
```

Once I switched from using a factory to using a service, I don't receive duplicates after a browser refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the above code in my AngularApp and found the events duplicating.
With the same Example from @pootzko using the SocketIoFactory

I have added a `unSubscribe(even_name)` inside the `$destroy` of the Controller, that will remove/clear the **socketEventListner**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
..
..
..
//Create a SocketIoFactory
app.service('SocketIoFactory', function($rootScope){

    console.log("SocketIoFactory....");
    //Creating connection with server
    var protocol = 'ws:',//window.location.protocol,
        host = window.location.host,
        port = 80,
        socket = null;
    var nodePath = protocol+'//'+host+':'+port+'/';

    function listenerExists(eventName) {
        return socket.hasOwnProperty("$events") && socket.$events.hasOwnProperty(eventName);
    }

    return {
        connect: function () {
            socket = io.connect(nodePath);
            console.log('SOCKET CONNECTION ... ',nodePath);
        },
        connected: function () {
            return socket != null;
        },
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            if (!listenerExists(eventName)) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        },
        unSubscribe: function(listener) {
            socket.removeAllListeners(listener);
        }
    };
});

..
..
..

//Use in a controller
app.controller("homeControl", ['$scope', 'SocketIoFactory', function ($scope, SocketIoFactory) {

  //Bind the events
  SocketIoFactory.on('<event_name>', function (data) {

  });

  //On destroy remove the eventListner on socketConnection
   $scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
        console.log('[homeControl] destroy...');
        SocketIoFactory.unSubscribe('<event_name>');
    });
}]);
```