# Why do my socket.on calls multiply whenever i recenter my controller

Tags: sockets, angularjs, socket.io

I've been using the socket factory described here by the brian ford here
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/

here is the factory
 myApp.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {

```
     var socket = io.connect('url');
        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },
            emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                })
            }
        };
    });
```

I have a socket.emit  in my  controllers initialization function and whenever i reenter this controller from another page the receiving socket.on  function executes +1 times. This happens until I manually refresh the page then it resets to 1. I don't explicitly store my socket in session. So what could be causing my socket.on to call multiple times.

Here is my socket.emt in my controller
this always executes once.

```
$scope.init = funciton (){
...
socket.emit('getSignedSlidesFromUrl', $scope.slideLocation);
}
```

Here is my socket.on that will be recieve 'getSignedSlidesFromUrl'

```
socket.on('signedUrls', function (signedSlides){
            console.log('signedUrls socket hit');
            $scope.slides = signedSlides;
            console.log($scope.slides[0]);
            console.log($scope.display);
        });
```

Here is an example of my console log after reentering the controller

about to emit getSignedSlidesFromUrl from init controllers.js:71

```
display after called $scope.first slide is0 controllers.js:574
flash object is controllers.js:537
signedUrls socket hit controllers.js:816
0 controllers.js:823
signedUrls socket hit controllers.js:816
0 controllers.js:823
```

if I reenter the controller again my log would change to

```
signedUrls socket hit controllers.js:816
0 controllers.js:823
signedUrls socket hit controllers.js:816
0 controllers.js:823
signedUrls socket hit controllers.js:816
0 controllers.js:823
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to add removeAllListeners to your factory (see below) and have the following code in each of your controllers:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
    socket.removeAllListeners();
});
```

Updated socket factory:

```
 var socket = io.connect('url');
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        },
      removeAllListeners: function (eventName, callback) {
          socket.removeAllListeners(eventName, function() {
              var args = arguments;
              $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
              });
          }); 
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: I added same code but still does not affect in code. Can you guide me? I add $destory in controller and add new removeAllListeners() method in socket.

Answer (score 1):

I tried @michaeljoser's solution, but it didn't work for me.

Then I found another solution and it worked

```
var socket = io.connect('url');
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        },
        getSocket: function(){ 
            return socket;
        }
    };
});
```

And in controller, I called

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
            socket.getSocket().removeAllListeners();
        });
```