# What to use instead of socket.removeAllListeners(); on the client side

Tags: sockets, angularjs, socket.io

I'm come across a similar problem to [Improve this AngularJS factory to use with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389049/how-to-use-angularjs-with-socket-io?rq=1) but the accepted answer seems to use a function that no longer exists so what would the substitute be for `socket.removeAllListeners();` on the client side in an angular.js controller if i need to remove a listener? I'm using socket.io v .9.16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`socket.removeAllListeners()` is still there. The reason why it couldn't be called is that the real **socket** is this one: `var socket = io.connect()`.

The "socket" in the following codes is a wrapper that angular factory returns, which only has two methods: `on` and `emit`.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
  socket.removeAllListeners();
  // or something like
  // socket.removeListener(this);
});
```

What you can do is to add a new `getSocket` methods to `socket` factory like this:

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      // ...
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      // ...
    },
    getSocket: function() {
      return socket;
    }
  };
});
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
  socket.getSocket().removeAllListeners();
  // or something like
  // socket.getSocket().removeListener(this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm still getting used to working with wrapper functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the code in the service itself, you can actually just add this to the object you're returning:

```
  removeAllListeners: function() {
     socket.removeAllListeners();
  }
```

Then in your controller, you'd just call `socket.removeAllListeners();`