# AngularJS using socket instead of http how can I get data traffic?

Tags: angularjs

Ours project using socket communicate with frontend to backend.unlike the http, I can't inspect traffic throuth fiddler.I do not know whether it can do this or not. I may wish I can set breakpoint to catch what infomation I want.

please help,thank you all.

BTW,This is the first time I met socket, in my eyes I treat it as http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this url:
[how to use AngularJS with Socket.IO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389049/how-to-use-angularjs-with-socket-io)

and  [Good tutorial for socket](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/)

When you are using socket, you have "Message" like function

```
 socket.on('message', function(data) {
        ...
 });
```

In above function you can set breakpoint to check and catch what data is coming from backend

Comment: yeah,but I do not mean that.I'm trying to create an AngularJS loading indicator, I wanna see the indicator thus,needed to pausing it to load the data.