# Angularjs socket.io eventlistener not getting removed

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I have an app with Node.js + Angular.js and socket.io

The socket is created as a factory as follows

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope, $window) {
    var socket = io.connect('', {
        query: 'token=' + $window.sessionStorage.token      
      }); //The token is included as part of JWT security. 
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    };
});
```

In the controller this socket is being injected

```
app.controller('MyController',function
                ($scope,$http,$routeParams,$rootScope,socket,$filter){
           . . . .
        });
```

and is being used as

```
dataList.forEach(function(dataNo){
   socket.on('DATA_CHANNEL:' + dataNo, function (data) {
    scope.resultData[index]['changed'] = data.changed; // some data change happens
   }             
});
```

All these works , but if I go to some other link in the app , these DATA_CHANNEL* listeners still exist. Because if I shut down the node.js server , I get the exception that the socket cannot connect etc. So they still exist.

I tried implementing ScopedSocket and removing all the listeners as mentioned here [Improve this AngularJS factory to use with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389049/how-to-use-angularjs-with-socket-io)
but still the listeners exist.

If I disconnect the socket , the Listners do not make any more calls , but then I am not able to connect the next time I come

Any suggestions on what can be done ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you'll get the "socket cannot connect" messages if you turn off the server as long as it goes off while you're connected to it. The heartbeat generates these messages. I don't think it's indicative of whether or not you have listeners still in existence.

Comment: @Houseman Sorry for the late reply . I guess you are correct , but a strange thing that I noticed is that

socket.removeAllListeners() - This removes all the event Listeners.  

socket.removeListeners('eventName', Fn); - This removes the function and replaces it with null, but the eventListeners remain there.

Is this the expected behaviour