# removing listeners socket.io and angular js

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, angularjs-factory

I have implemented a common socket.io angular [pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389049/improve-this-angularjs-factory-to-use-with-socket-io) but in my app I am having issues removing listeners. I added to my factory:

```
remove: function(name, fn) {
    socket.removeListener(name, fn);
}
```

Even though the function is getting called the listener is not being removed. How can I implement this?

I know of the [btford](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) module but I am far to advanced into development that implementing that module is out of the question at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Facing the same problem here, did you find the solution ?