# Change this websocket factory to socket.io factory in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, websocket, socket.io

Cause the backend use nodejs and socket.io,I have to change the frontend websocket service to socket.io to. But there some problems.
The websocket factory is defined below:

```js
app.factory("WebSocketDataProvider", function() {

 var WebSocketDataProvider = function(scope) {

  var queuedReqs = [];
  var wssock = null;
  var modelGraphIdIdx = {};


  function getWebSocket() {
   if ("WebSocket" in window) return new WebSocket(WS_URI);
      else if ("MozWebSocket" in window) return new MozWebSocket(WS_URI);
      else return null;
  }

  function onOpenWssock() {
   console.log("Connected. Extensions: [" + wssock.extensions + "]");
   console.log("Submitting queued requests:", queuedReqs.length);
   while(queuedReqs.length > 0) wssock.send(queuedReqs.shift());
  }

  function onCloseWssock(e) {
       console.log("Disconnected (clean=" + e.wasClean + ", code=" + e.code + ", reason='" + e.reason + "')");
      wssock = null;
     }
     function onMessageWssock(e) {
         var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
         if(data.error) {

          setGlobalAlerts(data);
          flashAlertsBar();
         } else if(data.annoEvents) {
          // annotations //
       scope.$apply(function(){scope.globalAnno.status = 'dispatching'});
       if(scope.modelType === 'adhoc') {
        data._id = scope.graph._id;
        var ce = new CustomEvent(data._id, {'detail': data });
        wssock.dispatchEvent(ce);
       } else {
        for(var i in modelGraphIdIdx) {
            data._id = i;
            var ce = new CustomEvent(data._id, {'detail': data });
            wssock.dispatchEvent(ce);
           }
       }
          scope.$apply(function(){scope.globalAnno.status = 'dispatched'});
         } else {
          // graph data //
          var ce = new CustomEvent(data._id, {'detail': data });
          wssock.dispatchEvent(ce);
         }
  }
  function initializeWebSocket() {
   wssock = getWebSocket();
   if(wssock !== null) {
       wssock.onopen   = onOpenWssock;
       wssock.onclose   = onCloseWssock;
       wssock.onmessage  = onMessageWssock;
      }
  }
  this.addGraphIdEventListener = function(graphId, funct) {
   wssock.addEventListener(graphId, funct);
   modelGraphIdIdx[graphId] = true;
   if(Object.keys(modelGraphIdIdx).length === scope.modelGraphIds.length) {
    // trigger annotation request as all graph elems are loaded //
    scope.globalAnno.status = 'load';
   }
  }
  this.removeGraphIdEventListener = function(graphId, funct) {
   if(wssock !== null) wssock.removeEventListener(graphId, funct);
  }
  this.requestData = function(query) {
      try {
    wssock.send(JSON.stringify(query));
      } catch(e) {

       if(e.code === 11) {
        queuedReqs.push(JSON.stringify(query));
       } else {
        //reconnect
        queuedReqs.push(JSON.stringify(query));
        initializeWebSocket();
       }
      }
     }
     this.closeConnection = function() {
      wssock.close();
     }
     initializeWebSocket();
 }
 return (WebSocketDataProvider);
});
```

I use this question [Improve this AngularJS factory to use with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389049/improve-this-angularjs-factory-to-use-with-socket-io) user65873' answer like this:

```js
var ScopedSocket = function (socket, $rootScope) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.listeners = [];
    this.childSockets = [];
};

ScopedSocket.prototype.removeAllListeners = function () {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < this.listeners.length; i++) {
        var details = this.listeners[i];
        this.socket.removeListener(details.event, details.fn);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < this.childSockets.length; i++) {
        this.childSockets[i].removeAllListeners();
    }
};

ScopedSocket.prototype.on = function (event, callback) {
    var socket = this.socket;
    var $rootScope = this.$rootScope;

    this.listeners.push({event: event, fn: callback});

    socket.on(event, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
    });
};

ScopedSocket.prototype.emit = function (event, data, callback) {
    var socket = this.socket;
    var $rootScope = this.$rootScope;

    socket.emit(event, angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(data)), function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            if (callback) {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
            }
        });
    });
};

ScopedSocket.prototype.of = function (channel) {
    var childSocket = new ScopedSocket(this.socket.of(channel), this.$rootScope);

    this.childSockets.push(childSocket);

    return childSocket;
};


app.factory('Socket', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    //var socket = $rootScope.socket;

    var queuedReqs = [];
    var modelGraphIdIdx = {};
    return function(scope) {
        var socket = io(WS_URI);
        var scopedSocket = new ScopedSocket(socket, $rootScope);

        scopedSocket.on('connect', function(){
            while(queuedReqs.length > 0) scopedSocket.emit('queuedReqs', queuedReqs.shift());
        });

        scopedSocket.on('error', function(data){
            setGlobalAlerts(data);
            flashAlertsBar();
        });

        scopedSocket.addGraphIdEventListener = function(graphId, funct) {
            scopedSocket.on(graphId, funct);
            modelGraphIdIdx[graphId] = true;
            if(Object.keys(modelGraphIdIdx).length === scope.modelGraphIds.length) {
                // trigger annotation request as all graph elems are loaded //
                scope.globalAnno.status = 'load';
            }
        }
        scopedSocket.removeGraphIdEventListener = function(graphId, funct) {
            if(scopedSocket !== null) scopedSocket.socket.removeListener(graphId, funct);
        }

        scopedSocket.requestData = function(query) {
            try {
                scopedSocket.emit('query', JSON.stringify(query));
            } catch(e) {

                if(e.code === 11) {
                    queuedReqs.push(JSON.stringify(query));
                } else {
           //reconnect
     queuedReqs.push(JSON.stringify(query));
    }
   }
  }

  scopedSocket.closeConnection = function() {
  }

  scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   scopedSocket.removeAllListeners();
  });
  return scopedSocket;
 };
}]);
```

but i got this error in console:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:3000/libs/angular/1.2.9/angular.min.js:6:449
at m (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular/1.2.9/angular.min.js:96:353)
at h.$apply (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular/1.2.9/angular.min.js:103:31)
at Socket.processRecievedData (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular-graphing.js:271:12)
at http://localhost:3000/app.js:747:22
at h.$eval (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular/1.2.9/angular.min.js:102:308)
at h.$apply (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular/1.2.9/angular.min.js:103:48)
at Socket.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/app.js:746:20)
at Socket.Emitter.emit (http://localhost:3000/libs/socket.io-client/socket.io.js:1194:20)
at Socket.onevent (http://localhost:3000/libs/socket.io-client/socket.io.js:832:10)
```

I don't know where is the wrong in my code. So I want to get some help.

Comment: The error has the description in it's link. Read more about it there. `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]` [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply)

Comment: Since it's async anyway, why don't you just use `$timeout` instead of calling `scope.$apply()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to bother doing all this hard work there is already an Angular interface ([btford-angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io)) for Socket.io, unless doing it for fun:

The error you are getting is because the `$apply` call is done while another `$apply` is in progress. It's  here:

```
else if (data.annoEvents) {
    // annotations //
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.globalAnno.status = 'dispatching'
    });
    if (scope.modelType === 'adhoc') {
        data._id = scope.graph._id;
        var ce = new CustomEvent(data._id, {
            'detail': data
        });
        wssock.dispatchEvent(ce);
    } else {
        for (var i in modelGraphIdIdx) {
            data._id = i;
            var ce = new CustomEvent(data._id, {
                'detail': data
            });
            wssock.dispatchEvent(ce);
        }
    }
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.globalAnno.status = 'dispatched'
    });
}
```

The problem is the code is executed so fast that, before the status is changed, is the scope of angular, to 'dispatching' the call for it to be changed to 'dispatched' is initiated. Just to test if your code works you can call `scope.$digest()` once in the end instead of calling `$apply()`:

```
else if (data.annoEvents) {
    // annotations //
    scope.globalAnno.status = 'dispatching'     // it will not be updated in the angular scope
    if (scope.modelType === 'adhoc') {
        data._id = scope.graph._id;
        var ce = new CustomEvent(data._id, {
            'detail': data
        });
        wssock.dispatchEvent(ce);
    } else {
        for (var i in modelGraphIdIdx) {
            data._id = i;
            var ce = new CustomEvent(data._id, {
                'detail': data
            });
            wssock.dispatchEvent(ce);
        }
    }
    scope.globalAnno.status = 'dispatched'
    scope.$digest();
}
```

The problem with the `$digest` call is that the `status='dispatching'` will not update in the angular scope so you will not be able to see it in the UI or somewhere else.

Now, you might want to rethink the architecture. I would suggest that you will use Angular events. If you think about it, you are already working with events from socket.io/websocket, so why not just make them work with angular. ([angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) has a similar approach so you can check it for an example)

Instead of storing the status on a variable `scope.globalAnno.status = 'dispatching'`, emit it from the root scope and use it where you need it: `$rootScope.$emit('socket:dispatching')`.

Comment: Thank you！ I changed websocket factory to angular-socket-io, and the code finally run without errors. :)